# How do I get my Maven plugin to execute as part of running a JUnit test in Eclipse?

Tags: maven, junit, maven-plugin, eclipse-mars, jpamodelgen

I’m using Eclipse Mars, JUnit 4.11, Hibernate 4.3.6.Final, and JPA 2.1.  I have imported a Maven project into Eclipse using the m2e plugin.  I have this plugin in my pom.xml file …

```
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.1.1</version>
                            <executions>
                                    <execution>
                                            <id>process</id>
                                            <goals>
                                                    <goal>process</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                                            <configuration>
                                                    <processors>
                                                            <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                                                    </processors>
                                            </configuration>
                                    </execution>
                            </executions>
                            <dependencies>
                                    <dependency>
                                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                                            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
                                    </dependency>
                            </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
```

If I have a domain class, “User”, the above plugin will generate a class “User_”, for use with JPA CriteriaBuilder queries.  Unfortunately, when I run my tests in Eclipse, I get errors like below (these do not happen when I run “mvn clean test -Dtest=MyTest” at the command line).

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyProjectOrganizationController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.mainco.subco.myproject.service.MyProjectOrganizationService org.mainco.subco.myproject.controller.MyProjectOrganizationController.m_MyProjectOrgSvc; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyProjectOrgService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.mainco.subco.myproject.repo.MyProjectOrganizationDao org.mainco.subco.myproject.service.MyProjectOrganizationServiceImpl.m_MyProjectOrganizationDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyProjectOrganizationDaoImpl' defined in file [/Users/davea/Documents/sb_workspace/core/target/classes/org/mainco/subco/myproject/repo/MyProjectOrganizationDaoImpl.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.mainco.subco.myproject.repo.MyProjectOrganizationDaoImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import org.mainco.subco.myproject.domain.MyProjectOrganization_ cannot be resolved
    The import org.mainco.subco.organization.domain.Organization_ cannot be resolved
    The import org.mainco.subco.url.domain.Url_ cannot be resolved
    MyProjectOrganization_ cannot be resolved to a variable
    MyProjectOrganization_ cannot be resolved to a variable
    MyProjectOrganization_ cannot be resolved to a variable
    MyProjectOrganization_ cannot be resolved to a variable
    Organization_ cannot be resolved to a variable
    Url_ cannot be resolved to a variable
    Organization_ cannot be resolved to a variable
    MyProjectOrganization_ cannot be resolved to a variable
    MyProjectOrganization_ cannot be resolved to a variable

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:102)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 25 more
```

The classes the error is complaining about are generated with the plugin I listed above, but for some reason, when I run JUnit tests (by right clicking on the class name in the Eclipse editor and selecting “Run As” -> “JUnit Test”), the plugin isn’t getting called.  How do I force my plugin to be run as part of executing a JUnit test in Eclipse?

Comment: You do not get any errors in maven, since the generate-sources lifecycle phase is reached before test. maven ensures, that be executing the plugin as configured that your generated sources are available during the compile phase and therefor will be available as compiled classes during test. Regenerating should only be necessary if you modify anything in your persistence classes rather then when executing the unit test.

Comment: One thing I can think of: Is your generated sources folder correctly imported in your eclipse ? I remember that eclipse sometimes doesn't recognize source folders from maven if the folder itself does not yet exist in the filesystem. Maybe execute a mvn clean compile and afterwards execute m2e again. Or manually add the generated sources folder as source folder to your eclipse project. Hope that helps ;-)